# RGB color picker for Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rgb, color-picker

**Status**: I am building an app in which is needed to be a field available for user to select a color, this field will contain RGB color code string.

I have tested one which looks pretty but it does not work very well. It is 'picky-color' and it is hosted in this repository: https://github.com/Astorsoft/picky-color. Here I open an issue about some problem with it.

**Problem**: Please suggest me some color picker to use in Rails 3 app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I selected [jPicker](http://www.digitalmagicpro.com/jPicker/), It was a good option for me.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps the list on the page [jQuery UI Development: Color Picker](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137750/ColorPicker) gives you the one that works out of the box. The reason for that is that jQuery is now included in Rails 3 applications, so using something on the base of Prototype or another JavaScript library is more difficult.

The integration in ruby should not be difficult, though.

Comment: mliebelt, Thank you very much for reply.
I'm testing some pickers refered in that page.
I will write here my conclusion.
Thank you very much again.

Comment: @mliebelt thanks for the link. I was surprised to see the OP list their favorite from the link and mark themselves with the correct answer.